# How do you get the difference between two timings int 24h clock format PHP

Tags: php

```
$start_hour = strtotime('2030');
$end_hour = strtotime('0100');

$resthour = abs(gmdate (strtotime($end_hour)- strtotime($start_hour)))/3600;
```

My current output is 19.5. My desired outcome should be 4.5.

Is there a better way in deriving that? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get close to the desired outcome, just add a simple line to check whether the different < 12 hours and convert it otherwise

```
$resthour = ($resthour >= 12) ? $resthour : 24 - $resthour;
```

This will work.
Regards,

Comment: Thank you! Did my own modifications on my database and it worked!